# Is it bad practice to create many Tasks and continuations and store them without starting?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have some consumer which consumes messages. And based on that message, I have to execute 3 type of async operation(`.net Task - TPL`) for each message. And for each message before executing those tasks i have to execute another tasks like `StartingDownloadMap` and `FinishedDoenloadMap`.
But, there are such constraints:

1) Only 10 number of tasks (same type) can be executed concurrently.

2) In case of same input parameters for any of that tasks, we can use already executing or already registered task. For example:

```
- Message1 -> England
- Message2 -> Italy
- Message3 -> Brazil
```

Let's say one of those 3 tasks is called, `DownloadEuropeMapPng`. And let's say that process will take 30 seconds. In such case, if I am executing `DownloadEuropeMapPng` for `England` message, and after 2 seconds I received a new message (f.e: Italy), then I have to attach new message process with already executing download task.

For fulfilling those requirements, I have created dictionary like this : Dictionary.
And I am using `.ContinueWith` and registering new tasks for executing.  And I have `if` block to check whether I am running 10 tasks or not for operation with specified type or not. (1st constraint)
And as those Tasks finished executing I am removing them from dictionary.

Is it bad to use tasks so heavy? Can it be a problematic? So, if I will have lets say 1000 messages at the same time. It is possible that I will create 3000 tasks, but only 30 of them will be running concurrently. Or I will have bunchs of registered continuation callbacks which will be executed after some time.

Comment: The usage scenario is not very clear without your code. Please, try to provide the minimal reproducible example of code instead of trying to explain it in words :)

Comment: And, what do you mean by `without starting`?

Comment: @Stefan I mean to create new Task and store it somewhere or create and start inside ContinueWith.

Comment: Where are your messages coming from? A message bus? AWS SQS? other?

Comment: @Stuart RabbitMQ

Comment: Why would you create 3000 tasks if you can only process 10 at a time? Just create tasks for the work you _can_ handle and leave the rest of the messages on the queue until you can get to them.

Answer (score 1):

Except for consuming some more memory, I see nothing wrong in having many task objects per se.  If you need to limit concurrency, you can do it in a much more simple way by creating a custom task scheduler like the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8).

Alternatively, you can also see Parallel.ForEach and specify [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: And what do you think of `TPL Dataflow`? I just read about that, it seems it is very useful in such complex scenarions. Because, with just Tasks the code seems unreadable.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, I woudn't consider your scenario very complex.  TPL DataFlows is fine, but you can just run your task sequence for every incoming message, and be done with it.  The Thread Pool will handle the max degree of parallelism by itself, and most probably do it better than what we programmers can decide. :-)

Comment: But what about adding continuation to the running task? Is it possible with DataFlow? Lets say, `DownloadMap` executing for England and it will continue for 30 seconds. After 5 seconds of starting downloading for `England`, I can receive new message with country which belongs o Europe. In such case, current;y I am getting runnning task from dictionary, and just adding another continuation for `Italy` as well. Is it possible with DataFlow? I can't find actually any article with such use-case of Tasks. That's why I worry a bit

Comment: Why would you use a continuation?  For me, downloading for England and for Italy are two separate, independent tasks.

Comment: I am downloading Europe map and it is same for both of them.
Actually, even I am a bit simpligying the case. And to be honest I am not downloading any map :) I just do some time -consuming process. But for the sake of the simplicity, I figured out such scenario –

Comment: Still, I don't understand why you need to use ContinueWith.